# can't retrieve correctly tagged photos of my friends with FQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm using FQL.I want to retrieve tagged photos of my friends.
And I'm using this Query.

```
SELECT pid,images FROM photo WHERE pid IN (
      SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE pid IN (
         SELECT pid,images FROM photo WHERE aid IN (
            SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner IN 
              SELECT uid,username,pic FROM user WHERE uid IN 
                SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
      ))))
```

But It retrieves less than I've expected.
I think that there's limit when retrieves photos from albums.

How do I retrieve more photos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered the similar question earlier on stackoverflow. Below is the link for same. In this I was fetching user's tagged photo. You can modify the same for friend's photo.

[How to retrieve ALL Facebook photos a person is tagged in](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7683230/how-to-retrieve-all-facebook-photos-a-person-is-tagged-in/11188122#11188122)

The GIST of the solution is that with your query you will never get complete data. I have tried the same in my app. For example for user which I tested there were 700+ photos. But the query similar to yours returned only 300+ photos.

So my suggestion is get the list of photoIDs i.e. object_id from photo_tags and use BATCH requests to fetch them.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Kaushik

Answer (score 0):

First of all, simplify your query: You don't need to look through `album`, so get rid of all that junk. To future-proof things, `object_id` is preferred to `pid`, so we'll use that.

```
SELECT object_id, images FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (
  SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN (
      SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) OR subject = me()
)
```

This returns 376 photos for me.

If you need more, you'll need to execute this query multiple times by adding `LIMIT [offset] [results]` to both your `photo` and `photo_tag` queries. If you use 500 for `[results]` you would use 0, 500, 1000, 1500... as values for `[offset]` as you loop through this query. Stop when it returns an empty array.